# Capture Ctrl-Enter in raw mode with getchar()?

Tags: linux, terminal, io

Is there any way to capture the key combination Ctrl-Enter when processing keystrokes with getchar() after setting the terminal to raw mode?

When test it, I just get the char value 10 which is the same whether Ctrl is held down or not.

Comment: You will want to look at [Why Is It so Hard to Detect Keyup Event on Linux?](http://blog.robertelder.org/detect-keyup-event-linux-terminal/). While it is simple in X, e.g. `"keysym 0xffe3, Control_L"` and `"keysym 0xff0d, Return"`, at the terminal the left-control is used as part of several escapes and interrupts (e.g. `Ctrl+C`). The char value `10` is simply the *newline* character. It apparently makes no difference whether you are in cannonical mode or not.

Answer (score 2):

After doing some more experimentation, it appears that most terminals do not send a unique keysym for Ctrl-Enter. By using a getchar loop you can see the full keysym codes for any terminal keypress:

```
// set terminal to raw, then...
while( int c = getchar() ) printf( "%d ", c );
```

Some keys like F1 and Ctrl-K will generate codes, but other key combinations will not. Ctrl-Enter unfortunately is not an encodable key combination. Of course, using signals with root access it can be detected from a local console, but not from a terminal.